# Problem installing Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8

Tags: installation, windows-8

I am able to install Ubuntu alongside windows 8 and beforehand I partitioned my harddrive and have 500gb unallocated space that I would like to use for Ubuntu. During Ubuntu installation, it does not prompt me to select my partition and instead goes straight into installation. Afterwards, when I startup my computer it boots straight into Windows. I then used EasyBCD to install an MBR. Now when I restart my computer Windows Boot shows up, but when I click Ubuntu it gives me an error.

When I enter Confirm-SecureBootUEFI into Windows Terminal I receive "False", meaning that Means my system has Secure boot and is Disabled. I feel that I have exhausted all options and I don't know what to do now.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported is a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

Make a clean install of ubuntu again in your system. But before doing that take a look at the following link. It might help you out solcing the problem:

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: I have looked at the link. I am not sure if the steps apply to me because my system has Secure Boot and is Disabled. Does it still apply?